# I need help finding a tangent line to a parabola.

Tags: geometry, tangent-line

This is the question.
A parabola $y=ax^2 + bx + x$ has vertex $A(2,1)$ and passes through $B(1,0)$. Find the equation of lines passing through $(0,4)$ that are tangent to the parabola.

Using a system of equations, I've already found the equation of the parabola to be $y=-x^2 + 4x -3$. However, since the point they give is not on the parabola, I have no clue how to find the pair of tangent lines. How should I do it?

Comment: The fastest way would be calculus. The slope of the line tangent to $y$ is called $y' = -2x + 4$.

Comment: You need to learn calculus. Khan Academy is an excellent resource for this.

Comment: @K.defaoite This can be solved without calculus. Tangent lines to a conic intersect it in exactly one point.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 I don’t see how using calculus is any faster than simply finding the lines through $(0,4)$ that intersect the curve in exactly one point. Either way, after about the same amount of algebraic manipulation you end up with a quadratic equation to solve.

Comment: Is there a typo in the first equation? Looks like the last term should be $c$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @amd You are right. I misunderstood the question.

Comment: @K.defaoite That’s not to say that the problem _can’t_ be solved using calculus, of course. I’m just going by the tags on the question, which don’t include “calculus.”

Answer (score 1):

The parabola is $$y=-x^2+4x-3~~~~~(1)$$ Let tangent to it from the point $(0,4)$ be $y-4=mx ~~~(2)$, putting this in (1), we get
$$mx+4=-x^2+4x-3 \implies x^2+(m-4)x+7=0$$ For tangency demand $B^2=4AC$ in this quadratic, to get $$(m-4)^2=28 \implies m=4\pm 2\sqrt{7}.$$ So the Eq. of tangents is
$$y=(4\pm 2 \sqrt{7}) x+4$$

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by taking the derivative of your function as follows:

$y'=-(x^2)'+(4x)'-3'=-2x+4$

Hence the function of the tangent is $-2x+4$.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: nevermind i confused myself

Answer (score 0):

First we know tangent slope at general point ${(x_1,y_1)}$ on the curve is  $$y'=(-2x+4)|_{(x_1,y_1)}$$ which is  $y'=-2x_1+4$ now assume that $y'$ is $m$ and find $x_1$ in tems of $m$ and later on you can find $y_1$ in terms of $m$ by the given equation of curve.Now we know $$y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$$ and we know $y_1$ and $x_1$ in terms of $m$.Now convert $y-y_1=m(x-x_1)$ in terms of $m,x,y$ and substitute the point $(0,4)$ in the equation which you got only in terms of $m,x,y$ and solve a quadratic in $m$ which will give you equation of tangents passing through point $(0,4)$.Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

From the vertex $(2,1)$, the parabola takes the form $y-1=a(x-2)^2$. Plug in the point $(1,0)$ to get
$$y= -(x-2)^2+1$$

Let $(p,q)$ be the tangent point and match the slope to get

$$y’= -2(p-2)= \frac{q-4}{p-0}$$

Solve to get $p=\pm \sqrt7$ and the corresponding slopes $\pm 2\sqrt7+4$. Then, use the point-slope formula to get the equations of the tangent lines

$$ y-4=(\pm2\sqrt7+4)x$$